# Windows 10 Startup Repair Loop doesn't let Windows to boot [Solved]

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

Yesterday my desktop froze and I had to tuned it off my pressing the start button. Afterwards, when Windows tried to boot, the Startup Repair popped out and tried to repair the startup with but giving an error and couldn't boot. It gave this rute: C:\Windows\System32\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt .

So I got access to troobleshoot options and I've tried everything: Windows can't reset, nor restore, nor repair startup, nor go back to the previous build, nor anything. I've tried enable/disabling everything in the Startup Options. I tried this with the options that just popped up in pc, and also trying through a bootable USB with Windows 10 in it. No luck.

I've tried also everything I could find in Internet to try with the Command Prompt, I've tried:

1. [This method](https://www.kapilarya.com/there-was-a-problem-refreshing-your-pc) in which I've to type:

   ```
   cd %windir%\system32\config 
   ren system system.001   
   ren software software.001
   ```
2. All the possible combinations of:

   ```
   bootrec /fixmbr
   bootrec /fixboot
   bootrec /scanos
   bootrec /rebuildbcd
   ```
3. I've also tried:

   ```
   bcdedit /export C:\BCD_Backup
   c:
   cd boot
   attrib bcd -s -h -r
   ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old
   bootrec /RebuildBcd
   ```
4. Restoring the MBR:

   ```
   bootsect /ntfs60 C:
   ```
5. Checking the disk (I took like 4 hours and I got nothing):

   ```
   sfc /scannow
   chkdsk /r
   ```
6. Alternatively this:

   ```
   sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=c:\windows
   chkdsk c: /r
   ```
7. [BillyBigun's method](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-10-bootrec-fixboot-access-is-denied/747c4180-7ff3-4bc2-b6cc-81e572d546df) involving:

   ```
   Diskpart
   List disk
   Sel disk 0
   List vol
   Sel vol 4
   assign letter=V:
   Exit
   V:
   format V: /FS:FAT32
   bcdboot C:\windows /s V: /f UEFI
   ```

During all that I've tried, I've found troubles like "Access denied" while performing /fixboot, which I solved somehow trying different things. One of them was maybe:

```
bootsect/nt60 sys
```

Other issues I've found is when I tried bootrec /rebuildbcd, where I got the message:

```
Total identified Windows installations: 0
```

I've fixed it by using diskpart:

```
Diskpart
List disk
Sel disk 0
List vol
Sel vol 2
active
```

Then, when trying /rebuildbcd I got the message:

```
Successfully scanned Windows installations.
Total identified Windows installations: 1
[1]  D:\Windows
Add installation to boot list? Yes<Y>/No<N>/All<A>:
```

The thing is that in the selection of the volumen in diskpart, sometimes it works by selecting vol 1 and sometimes vol 2, I don't know why.

However, I think I screwed something up while doing the formatting part in the BillyBigun's method because since then when I turn the pc on, Startup Repair doesn't show up but a blue Recovery screen instead with the error 0xc0000225 and some options. I think the boot folder is gone or something, and I've not been able to fix it. Of course I've tried everything and nothing solves it. But I can load the Troobleshot options using the bootable USB.

I've trying re-installing Windows, but when I proceed to do so and select "Update" instead of a Clean Instalation (which is not an option, since there's stuff on the PC I don't have a back up of), I got the error message:

> Compatibility report: 
>   The computer started using the windows installation media. Remove the installation media and restart your computer so that windows starts normally. Then, insert the installation media and restart the upgrade. (Do not select Icustom [advanced] to perform an upgrade Icustom [advanced] installs a new copy of windows and deletes your programs and settings.)

And I've not been able to fix that yet. And I've also face the error code 0xc000000f after this.

One thing is that I took all the codes above from my sources, so I don't really use the letter/numbers that are showed, what I currently have is:

While typing diskpart:

```
Disk ###    Status Size    Free    Dyn Gpt
Disk 0      Online 465 GB  1024 KB
Disk 1      Online  14 GB     0 B
```

Disk 0 is my hard-drive and Disk 1 is my bootable USB. While typing 'list vol':

```
Volume ###   Ltr  Label  Fs     Type       Size    Status    Info
Volume 0      F                 DVD-ROM       0 B  No Media
Volume 1      D   V      FAT32  Partition  313 MB  Healthy
Volume 2      C          NTFS   Partition  465 GB  Healthy
Volume 3      E          NTFS   Partition  450 MB  Healthy   Hidden
Volume 4      G          FAT32  Partition   14 GB  Healthy
```

If I type 'sel disk o' and then 'list part' I got:

```
Partition ### Type     Size    Offset
Partition 1   Primary  313 MB   31 KB
Partition 2   Primary  465 GB  313 MB
Partition 3   Recovery 450 MB  465 GB
```

The volume that I formatted while trying BillyBigun's method was Volume 1, it was a NTFS before.

Since I ran out of option, I'm posting here, I don't now if I can or if I should post elsewhere, sorry!

I understand that it's a mess, but I tried to express all things I've tried (and that was a mess) the better I could. Sorry!

Any help or suggestion is really appreciated. Even if I'm just able to start Windows once, to backup my files and then do a proper clean up, it would be nice!

Thank you for readying and thanks in advance!

---

**tl;dr**: Windows 10 doesn't start. Right now I'm getting
[this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1UWY.jpg).I tried all the showed options and got nothing. I tried using a bootable USB with Windows 10 but can't repair my PC boot. (Can't restore, can't reset, can't go back to a previous build, etc.). I tried a lot of things on Command Prompt and I've not been able to fix it yet. I think the boot folder/partition is broken, damaged or deleted. What can I do? Thanks!

---

Some other links I've checked (I've actually checked a lot more, but is not worth it to share them):

- [How to fix Bootrec /fixboot Access is denied during to fix Boot Configuration Data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rczKC7w302U)
- [How to Fix Error Code 0xc0000225 Windows 10 - Fixed Easily](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkJUcmDxeX8)
- [Your PC needs to be repaired, Error 0xc0000225 on Windows 10/8 (Solved)](https://www.repairwin.com/fix-your-pc-needs-to-be-repaired-error-0xc0000225/)

Comment: You may need to simply wipe and reinstall. I hope you have backups of your files, or can back them up if you boot from a USB.

Comment: I don't have a backup of my files. I'm trying to boot from a USB, but I can't, just the options "Continue" and "Troobleshooting" appear, not the "Use a device" (which I think is the one).

Comment: Anytime when kinda like that issue happened, the first thing one need to do is to check health of HDD by extracting SMART attributes from internal HDD's controller by running GSmartControl or similar utility that can read SMART. If GSmartControl show any light or dark red row(s) on attributes then HDD is failing. If windows won't boot, then extract hard drive and test it on another PC or use some Live Linux CD by running `smartctl -a /dev/sda` when Linux started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do now is to back up as much data as you can extract.

Three option for accessing the data:

- If you have another PC with an empty drive socket, remove the HDD and put it in as a secondary (non-boot) disk.
- If you need to buy a HDD enclosure, they can be found from [US$10 and up](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_8/146-3390695-3664618?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=hard%20disk%20enclosure&sprefix=disk%20enc%2Caps%2C154&crid=3U74QQTBFDF77). Mounted in an enclosure, you can try to read the data from another PC.
- Make a Live USB of another OS, e.g. [Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0). Running from the USB flash drive, mount the HDD partitions that still work as read-only and transfer data to another place, whether an external HDD, a large flash USB drive, or the cloud.

Then you can fix the disk any way you want, even formatting it and letting a Windows ISO re-partition as needed. Or give up on Windows and switch to another OS: Linux takes less than a half hour to install from scratch.

Comment: I don't have a PC with a second slot and buying a HDD enclosure is not possible where I live (Venezuela is not easy), but I can try 3rd option. Can you guide me in the process? I've already an .iso from Ubuntu 14.04.2 L and Ubuntu 16.04.1, does any of these work?

Comment: It worked! I used a Ubuntu bootable USB and could back up my files, then proceed to re-install Windows with a Windows 10 bootable USB. The weird (but good I guess) part is that the backup wasn't needed, because I was able to perform a Custom Instalation and my files were stored in Windows.old (which I think I wasn't able to do). So pc is working right now, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped... I keep a Live Ubuntu version, as well as Windows PE, on USB drives for just such repairs.